# NAVIGATION DRAWER :- NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()

Tags: android

[DRAWER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAIIl.png)Hello friends i'm using Navigation drawer in my project but facing with the above error while trying to open an activity onclick of listview-listitem (2nd time) the app run perfectly at very first time when we click on the list item but if we go back and click any item of drawer menu and after that if we try to click on listitem the error occurs 
[LIST VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1GwL.png)

```
FRAGMENT.java


package com.forever.technology.bscit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.forever.technology.bscit.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Sem1Fragment_list extends ListFragment {




    public Sem1Fragment_list() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sem1_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.sem1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Subject1Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.forever.technology.bscit;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set the fragment initially
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        //How to change elements in the header programatically

      /*  View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        emailText.setText("newemail@email.com"); */

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem1) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            Sem1Fragment fragment = new Sem1Fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem2) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            Sem2Fragment fragment = new Sem2Fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem3) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem4) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem5) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem6) {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_blogs) {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_site) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Subject1.activity

```
package com.forever.technology.bscit;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Subject1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subject1);
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
03-23 01:06:33.111 11547-11547/com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial, PID: 11547
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
   at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
   at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
   at com.forever.technology.bscit.Sem1Fragment_list.onListItemClick(Sem1Fragment_list.java:50)
   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please paste logcat output containing the crash logs.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari added logcat output

Comment: "but if we go back and click any item of drawer menu" what is drawer menu? Can you please show us a screenshot or something?

Comment: @prudhvi  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAIIl.png

Comment: @prudhvi  http://i.stack.imgur.com/C1GwL.png

Comment: So your app is crashing when you click on Sem1 or Subject1?

Comment: SEM1>SUBJECT1>working fine but again SEM1 or any other DRAWER MENU >SUBJECT1>APP CRASH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you're starting a different Fragment `Sem1Fragment` from the `MainActivity`. So the actual Fragment which has the list i.e `Sem1Fragment_list` is not having the context needed to launch `Subject1Activity`. So just replace the `Sem1Fragment` with `Sem1Fragment_list` in your Navigation Drawer code as shown below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView = null;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set the fragment initially
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        //How to change elements in the header programatically

      /*  View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        emailText.setText("newemail@email.com"); */

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_exit) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem1) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            Sem1Fragment_list fragment = new Sem1Fragment_list();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //add this to restore the fragment when back button is pressed
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem2) {
            //Set the fragment initially
            Sem2Fragment fragment = new Sem2Fragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem3) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem4) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem5) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sem6) {

        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_blogs) {

            try {
                //If App installed
                Intent intent;
                intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.forevertech.app");
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) { //google play app is not installed
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forevertech.app"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_site) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.abaagekya.com/"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working :-  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: If you click on the list item 2nd time without clicking the navigation drawer, does it crash?

Comment: So I think the problem is you lose your Activity's context when you click on navigation drawer and by the time you click on list item your Activity's context might not be there. Just to confirm, for the first time try to click on navigation drawer and then on list item and see if it's crashing.

Comment: Let me give a last try here or else we can chat in Android room. Give me some time, I'm working on it.

Comment: bro i have send the mail

Comment: THANKS @prudhiv  IT'S WORKING FINE

Comment: @prudhvi You provided the alternative solution by removing Sem1Fragment from the picture. What if Sem1Fragment is required ?

Comment: The implementation itself is wrong. If Sem1Fragment is required then the actual list should be in it and not in Sem1Fragment_list.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `Sem1Fragment.java` code.
You are having the static reference "rootView" of your inflated view. On again selecting the same fragment from the `NavigationDrawer`, you are again instantiating the same fragment but since your inflated view reference is static , it will not be refreshed and will contain the stale context and hence `getContext()` is null.
Thus,
Change your  code -

```
static View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sem1, container, false);
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

by

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sem1, container, false);
    }
```

> One more improvement

- You should check in `onNavigationItemSelected()` whether the fragment you are trying to instantiate is already visible, then don't instantiate it again.

Comment: Could you explain why, please?

Comment: Because getContext(() is null and hence it throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Yes, but *why* is it null? `getAcitivity()` returns a `Context` object. You have a code only answer and I'm trying to get you to update the answer with more description.

Comment: I just figured out the error from the logs. There has to be some more code pasted by the author in order to figure out why getContext() is null.

Comment: sorry bro its not working the activity is opening only for the first time and throwing error for the second time

Comment: Please add NavigationDrawer related code so as to identify the root cause.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari can you share your mail-id

Comment: Sorry, you have to conitnue it here.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari it will be complex to share all the related codes over here so please share your mail id or Skype id please solve it got stucked from last five days

Comment: @ShadabAnsari added all the required code please look for it and please solve the error

Comment: @ShadabAnsari THANKS IT'S WORKING FINE

Answer (score 0):

Refer to any Navigation Drawer example on web. You have to implement Nav Drawer in a Base Activity & all your activities should extend the BaseActivity.

Here is my working code :

**BaseActivity**

```
package com.projects.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ajay.projects.adapters.NavigationDrawerListAdapter;
import com.ajay.projects.models.Items;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author ajay.barve@gmail.com
 *         <p/>
 *         This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to navigation drawer.
 *         We are going to extend all our other activities from this BaseActivity so that every activity will have Navigation Drawer in it.
 *         This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    /**
     * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list.
     */
    protected static int position;
    /**
     * This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
     */
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    /**
     * Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
     * This layout is protected so that child activity can access this
     */
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    /**
     * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
     * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened.
     */

    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    /**
     * List item array for navigation drawer items.
     */
    protected String[] listArray = {"About CML Dashboard", "About Jaslok Onchology Department", "View Report", "Add Record", "CBC Trend", "Tabular Report"};
    protected ArrayList<Items> _items;
    boolean dataExists = false;
    /**
     * Base layout node of this Activity
     */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    /**
     * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _items = new ArrayList<Items>();
        _items.add(new Items("About Jaslok Hospital", "Lean about Jaslok Hospital & Jaslok onchology department", R.drawable.item_1));
        _items.add(new Items("View Report", "View CBC Reports stored int he device", R.drawable.item_2));
        _items.add(new Items("Add Record", "Add a new CBC Report", R.drawable.item_3));
        _items.add(new Items("CBC Trend", "View trends of each parameter in CBC Report", R.drawable.item_4));
        _items.add(new Items("Tabular Report", "View tabular   CBC Report", R.drawable.item_5));
        //Adding header on list view
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_header_layout, null);
        mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerListAdapter(this, _items));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
                Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onItemClick-Enter");
            }
        });

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.aj_launcher,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */ {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    /*End of OnCreate*/

    /*Start OnClick*/
    /* Comment : Have to implement with the OnClickListner onClick is called when a view has been clicked.*/
    public void onClick(View v) { // Parameter v stands for the view that was clicked.

        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onClick:Enter");
        final Context context = this;
    }
    /*End of onClick*/

    /**
     * @param position Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "openActivity-Enter");
        /**
         * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
         * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
         * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
         * So that we are setting this in child activity.
         */
//      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      setTitle(listArray[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AddActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TrendActivity.class));
                break;
            case 5:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, TabularActivity.class));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

//      Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onCreateOptionsMenu-Enter");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-Enter");
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-Enter"+item);
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onOptionsItemSelected-getItemId"+item.getItemId());

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    //@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onPrepareOptionsMenu-Enter");
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onBackPressed-Enter");
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Log.e("Logger:BaseActivity", "onItemSelected-Enter");

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

}
```

---

**HomeActivity**

```
package com.projects.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ajay.projects.adapters.HomeScreenGridViewAdapter;

/**
 * @author ajay.barve@gmail.com
 */
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {


    //private GridView gridview;
    private ListView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * We will not use setContentView in this activty Rather than we will
         * use layout inflater to add view in FrameLayout of our base activity
         * layout
         */

        /**
         * Adding our layout to parent class frame layout.
         */
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home_layout, frameLayout);

        /**
         * Setting title and itemChecked
         */
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);

        initializeActivity();
    }

    private void initializeActivity() {

        gridview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new HomeScreenGridViewAdapter(this, _items));
    }
}
```

---

Code is self explanatory. Hope this example helps.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I was not aware we should not be addressing people by name in the reply